# How to use surefire plugin to run test in customized folder structure

Tags: java, maven, testing, junit, maven-surefire-plugin

I have a customized eclipse studio project. For unit testing we are creating a test file under -

```
  TestJavaSrc/demoTest.java
```

Now this TestJavaSrc folder is on the same level as of POM.xml
Here is POM.xml -

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<project>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.demo.test</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.19.1</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Now when I run this project as mvn test , it is not able to find any test files.
And also , when I run following command on command line -

```
 mvn "-Dtest=TestJavaSrc/DemoTest.java" test
```

It gives me error-

```
 Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.19.1:test
 (default-test) on project demo: No tests were executed! 
 (Set -DfailIfNoTests=false to ignore this error.) -> [Help 1]
```

Also , I have JUnit4 in my classpath

Is there anything I am missing?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the Maven [standard directory layout](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html), unit tests written in Java should be located under `src/test/java`:

> The `src` directory contains all of the source material for building the project, its site and so on. It contains a subdirectory for each type: `main` for the main build artifact, `test` for the unit test code and resources, site and so on.

As such, the Surefire Plugin will execute the tests that are exactly in that folder; this is configurable through the [`testSourceDirectory`](http://maven.apache.org/components/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html#testSourceDirectory) parameter. Note that this directory is the base source directory that contains all of the tests. This means that if that base directory is `somedir` and there is a Java class called `DemoTest.java`, declared to be in the package `foo.bar`, then the file on disk must be located in `somedir/foo/bar/DemoTest.java`.

This is where the parameter [`test`](http://maven.apache.org/components/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html#test) that you're (mis)using enters: it selects the Java class to execute by its name only; not by its package declaration nor by the location of the file on disk.

I'd recommend that you place your test class in that standard directory, but if you truly want to do this, there are multiple options:

1. If you want to have a single test source directory, which is `TestJavaSrc`, located at the base directory of the Maven project, then you can configure it in your POM with:

   ```
   <build>
     <testSourceDirectory>${project.basedir}/TestJavaSrc</testSourceDirectory>
   </build>
   ```
2. If you want to have a special directory just for that lone test, which is to say that you want to keep the default `src/test/java`, but want to additionally consider this new source directory, then you can use the [`add-test-source`](http://www.mojohaus.org/build-helper-maven-plugin/add-test-source-mojo.html) goal of the Build Helper Maven Plugin:

   ```
   <plugin>
     <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
     <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
     <version>1.12</version>
     <executions>
       <execution>
         <id>add-test-source</id>
         <goals>
           <goal>add-test-source</goal>
         </goals>
         <configuration>
           <sources>
             <source>TestJavaSrc</source>
           </sources>
         </configuration>
       </execution>
     </executions>
   </plugin>
   ```

Note that both approaches imply that the `demoTest.java` file, which is directly under that folder, will be in the default package, so it must not have a `package` declaration.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are not using `src/test/java` at all for tests, you can instruct the build to use a different directory, e.g.:

```
<build>          
    ...
    <testSourceDirectory>${project.basedir}/TestJavaSrc</testSourceDirectory>
    ...
</build>
```